# Select column names and types of a table

Tags: c#, postgresql

I'm writing a c# program that accesses a PostgreSQL Database.
Since my program is supposed to work generically, I need to get the column names and the corresponding data types dynamically.

My code looks something like this:

```
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns", connection);
OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\dummy5.txt"))
{
    while (reader.Read() == true)
    {                    
        s = reader.GetString(0) + "\t" + reader.GetString(1);
        file.Write(s + "\n");
    }                
}
```

The results I get look like this:

> C_PK  12
>
> C_URI 12
>
> C_REV -5
>
> C_CREATED 93
>
> C_HOMEPAGECONTENT 12
>
> C_ID  12

The column names are  correct but the corresponding data types are represented as a number. These numbers are consistent ( 12 is a string, -5 long, 93 DateTime).

Since I'm both new to C# and SQL I don't really know where exactly the mistake is. Is the query already wrong or has it something to do with the representation of SQL data types in C#?

Comment: Whats your actual need??.Why do you want to get `column_name` and `data_type` like this??.Are you trying to dynamically selects values by specifying `data type` and `table name` from `information_schema`

Comment: Try `SELECT column_name, data_type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name='your_table'` by specifying table name

Comment: @winged panther: The result when specifying the table name is pretty much the same (only that I get fewer results, since I'm not quering every table in the database). One of the things my program should do, is look inside a database and look up what kind of information is stored inside a table. For that I need to know the column names and the data type of that columns, i.e. if it's a string, a date or something like that. The code snipped I posted kind of does that, but instead of 'string' it returns '12'.